# Iterating through a list via a method call

Tags: c#

I am entering code into a list.  However, when I try to iterate through the code in a method call, nothing is being returned.

The problem code is found in "public class iterating".  I am not sure why it won't execute.

Basically, I would like someone to enter information.  Once the information has been entered, I would then like the user to iterate through the list via a method call.

```
 using System;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;


public class Iterating
{
    List<String> employees = new List<String>();

    public void Test2()
    {
        //This is where I am trying to iterate//
        for (int i = 0; i < employees.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(employees[i]);
        }
    }
}

public class Testing
{
    public void Test1()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            List<String> employees = new List<String>();

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"((.{5})-\d{2,5}-\d{2,5})|(@.*.com)");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter an e-mail");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if(string.Equals(input, "quit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have quit the program");
                break;
            }
            else if (match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
                employees.Add(match.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Testing T1 = new Testing();
        T1.Test1();
        Iterating I1 = new Iterating();
        I1.Test2();
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the code you posted to make it readable, but this code does not compile. I am not sure what you mean by "nothing is being returned", as this code stands it won't run because it won't compile. To answer what I think your question is - you would probably need to find a way to share the employee list between the two classes/methods.

Comment: The two lists are in different classes/objects. You need to copy employees from T1 to I1

Answer (score 1):

You don't get any output since

1. Every loop in the collection stage uses a new `employees` list.
2. Your two classes do not share the same `employees` list - they each have their own separate list.
   If you want the iterating class to print the contents of a list, you need to pass it the list in question.

A partial example:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        List<String> employees = new List<String>();
        Testing T1 = new Testing();
        T1.Test1(employees);
        Iterating I1 = new Iterating();
        I1.Test2(employees);
    }
}
```

You would modify your test methods to use the passed list rather than create new ones

Comment: You could also mention that the answer to "nothing being returned" is that the method is a void method so there isn't a return value.

Comment: It often happens where the phrase "not returning anything" is used in lieu of "not doing anything." Here it is clear (to me) that OP expected console feedback but nothing was "getting returned" to it.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   public class Iterating {
>     List<String> employees = new List<String>();
>
>     public void Test2()
>     {
>         //This is where I am trying to iterate//
>         for (int i = 0; i < employees.Count; i++)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine(employees[i]);
>         }
>     } 
>    }
> ```

employees is always empty since this doesn't have anything to do with Testing.employees you might want to remove it and pass the list into Test2 or into the constructor.

Also, Testing.employees should be outside the while look

You can redesign your class like this

```
public class Iterating
{    
    public void Test2(List<String> employees)
    {
        //This is where I am trying to iterate//
        for (int i = 0; i < employees.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(employees[i]);
        }
    }
}

public class Testing
{
    public List<String> Test1()
    {
        List<String> employees = new List<String>();//this should be outside the while loop
        while (true)
        {    
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"((.{5})-\d{2,5}-\d{2,5})|(@.*.com)");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter an e-mail");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if(string.Equals(input, "quit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have quit the program");
                break;
            }
            else if (match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Value);//where is the match var
                employees.Add(match.Value);//where is the match var
            }
        }

        return employees;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Testing T1 = new Testing();
        var employees = T1.Test1();
        Iterating I1 = new Iterating();
        I1.Test2(employees);
    }
}
```